# Django templated does not display inputs to be filled

Tags: django, django-forms

I need a call a form on an HTML template where the user posts data which saves to model
The code is running without any errors
But the html page display only title and button
No text input fields

I have a form which is to be displayed on a html page so the user can input data and it saves the data into the model.I am not getting any errors while executing th code but the template does not display the form it just shows the title and submit button

```
def boqmodel1(request):
form = boqform(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    obj=form.save(commit=False)
    obj.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'create.html', context)
else:
    context = {'error': 'The post has been successfully created.
```

Please enter boq'}
        return render(request, 'create.html', context)

MyTemplate

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Create boq"/>
</form>
```

MY Url

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^create/', views.boqmodel1, name='boqmodel1'),
path('', views.boq, name='boq'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your first request, without submitting form is GET. When you submit a form you send POST.

The form is not displaying, because your form is not valid in the first place. Your function should look like this:

```
def boqmodel1(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == "GET":
        form = boqform()
        context["form"] = form

    # if you post a form do all the saving 
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = boqform(request.POST)
        context = {'form': form}
        if form.is_valid():
            obj=form.save()

            return render(request, 'create.html', context)
        else:
            context["errors"] = form.errors

    return render(request, 'create.html', context)
```

If method is GET init your form and pass it to your context, so you can display it  on frontend. 
If method is POST, init your form with your data from frontend (request.POST), check if the form is valid. If it is valid - save it. If it is not valid, return your errors and display them as you wish.